# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

I have some problem with my route.
when i post an update, the error come

> **Here's my Form**

This is maybe wrong at the form action attr, but i think is already fine.

```
 @foreach ($products as $p)
 <form action="{{ url('edit_product/', $p->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @method('patch')
 @csrf
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="product_id">Id Produk</label>
     <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $p->id }}" class="form-control" id="product_id" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="product_name">Example label</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" value="{{ $p->product_name }}" autofocus="" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="image">Pilih Gambar</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="preview-image">Gambar saat ini</label><br>
     <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/admin/image/{{ $p->image }}" alt="{{ $p->image }}" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="preview-image">Preview Gambar Terbaru</label><br>
     <img src="" id="preview-image" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="description">Deskripsi</label>
     <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" autocomplete="off">{{ $p->description }}</textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="type">Tipe</label>
     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
     @foreach ($products as $p)
       <option value="{{ $p->id }}" name="type" {{ (isset($p->id) || old('id'))? "selected": "" }}>{{ $p->type }}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="price">Harga</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="{{ $p->price }}" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Simpan">
   </div>
 </form>
 @endforeach
```

> **Here's my DataTable**

i think i got a problem in the href attr, nut i don't know where's the problem is.

```
 <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center" style="width:100%">
      <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Nama Produk</th>
          <th>Gambar</th>
          <th>Deskripsi</th>
          <th>Tipe</th>
          <th>Harga</th>
          <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="test">
      @foreach ($products as $p)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
          <td>{{ $p->product_name }}</td>
          <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/admin/image/{{ $p->image }}" alt="{{ $p->image }}" style="width: 160px; height: 80px;"></td>
          <td>{{ $p->description }}</td>
          <td>{{ $p->type }}</td>
          <td>{{ $p->price }}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="/admin/product/{{ $p->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ubah Data"><i class="far fa-edit "></i>
            </a> |
            <form action="{{ $p->id }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
            @method('delete')
            @csrf
              <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini?');" class="btn btn-danger" title="Hapus Data"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

> **Here's my Route**

Are write id like this is a right way?

```
Route::get('/admin/product/{id}/edit', 'Admin\AdminProductController@edit')->name('edit_product');
Route::patch('/admin/product/{id}', 'Admin\AdminProductController@update')->name('update_product');
```

> **Here's my Controller**

I'm always got a problem at 'products'

```
public function edit(Product $products)
{
    $products = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('admin.partials.product.edit-product', compact('products'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\admin\AdminProduct  $adminProduct
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
        $name = $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $files->move('admin/image', $name);
        DB::table('products')->where('id', $request->id)->update([
            'image' => $name,
            'product_name' => $request->product,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'price' => $request->price
        ]);
    }
    return redirect('/admin/product')->with('message', 'Successfull Save Your Image file.');
}
```

Comment: Do you know where is the problem ? It's Laravel 7 you can see exactly where you are getting this error message, maybe in blade or controller,I want to know what debug method have you tried so far ?

Comment: Why you are not using laravelcollective : here is the link https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html ? and `composer require laravelcollective/html` to install

Comment: Why there is `@foreach ($products as $p)` in single product edit form ?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try, it is untested but this time you will know where the problem is because i added try catch block, plus ID in the parameters

```
public function edit(Product $products, $id = 0)
    {
        try{
            $products = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->first();
            if($products === null){
                return redirect()->back()->with([
                    'status'    => 'danger',
                    'message'   => 'Invalid Product Id.'
                ]);
            }
            return view('admin.partials.product.edit-product', compact('products'));
        }catch (Exception $exception){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'danger',
                'message'   => $exception->getMessage(),
                'lineNum'   => $exception->getLine()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id = 0)
    {
        try{
            $checkIfProductExist = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->first();
            if($checkIfProductExist === null){
                return redirect()->back()->with([
                    'status'    => 'danger',
                    'message'   => 'Invalid Product Id'
                ]);
            }
            if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $files = $request->file('image');
                foreach ($files as $file){
                    $files->move('admin/image', $file);
                    DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->update([
                        'image'         => $file->getFilename(),
                        'product_name'  => $request->product,
                        'description'   => $request->description,
                        'type'          => $request->type,
                        'price'         => $request->price
                    ]);
                }
            }
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'success',
                'message'   => 'Images Saved Successfully.'
            ]);
        }catch (Exception $exception){
            return redirect()->back()->with([
                'status'    => 'danger',
                'message'   => $exception->getMessage(),
                'lineNum'   => $exception->getLine()
            ]);
        }
    }
```